# Lyx, Is it possible to hide a section in editing mode?

Tags: lyx

im working on a paper and sometimes i get pretty lost in in, is it possible to close some parts down only while editing?
example: in code editors like pycharm the is an option to close an indented block of code to make it clearer to the eye. it the anything like this in Lyx?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, however there are some workarounds that you might decide are better than nothing, which I will give details on below.

The feature you are looking for is called [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding). Although many LyX developers and users would like to have this feature in LyX, we have not had a volunteer to work on it. You can see a lot of interest on [this LyX feature request Wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/FeaturePoll2) as well as [this 15-years-old enhancement request](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2039).

The workaround I'm familiar with are the following:
- You could use "branches". Just put all of the text you would like to "fold" inside a LyX branch that is activated. You can easily close and open a branch inset.
- You can use child documents. This makes your text more modular and you can work on each child document separately.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can by child:

- insert new child.
- cut your section and past it in the new child.
- closed the child.

now you hide it,and you can hide it from pdf by enable or disable the child.